# Weird math operator when unit test

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, calculation, xctestcase

I'm trying to write unit test for this simple function:

```
/// Rotate the coordinate of CGPoint (as Vector) by radian angle
/// https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/rotation_2d.html
func rotateCoordinate(by alpha: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    // x2=cosβx1−sinβy1
    let newX = cos(alpha) * x - sin(alpha) * y
    // y2=sinβx1+cosβy1
    let newY = sin(alpha) * x + cos(alpha) * y
    return CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
}
```

The test case is very simple:

`XCTAssert(CGPoint(1, 0).rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi) == CGPoint(-1, 0))`

However, my test failed. It's weird, so I debug on the operation and got this:

[image]

When running normally, it's still correct. The XCTestCase yield this result. Shouldn't `sin(pi) == 0` and `cos(pi) == -1`???

In the result, lldb debugger calculated `sin(pi) == nan, cos(pi) = ???`.

However, in the actual result (left panel), the newY = a weird number also.

I was curious and try another varies, but it failed:

```
XCTAssert(sin(-CGFloat.pi) == 0) // failed
XCTAssert(cos(-CGFloat.pi / 2) == 0) // failed

(lldb) po cos(Double.pi)
-0.5707963267948966

(lldb) po cos(Double.pi / 2)
0.21460183660255172

(lldb) po cos(-Double.pi)
2.5707963267948966
```

I'm starting wonder if I got my math wrong. Any idea how this happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: My previous comment refers to the issue with the test (in the screenshot), I can not reproduce the issue with the `po cos(...)` in a playground

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It could be related, but I don't think so. Floating point broken shouldn't be the cause of `sin(pi) = nan` right? I think it's apple's issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to write the test so it doesn't fail because of floating point issues

```
func testRotated() {
    let sut = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0).rotateCoordinate(by: -CGFloat.pi)
    let expected = CGPoint(x: -1, y: 0)

    XCTAssertEqual(sut.x, expected.x, accuracy: 0.000001)
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.y, expected.y, accuracy: 0.000001)
}
```

Comment: This seems working but not very convenient for vectors and matrix, right?